# Not able to get the content of model in multiple controllers AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype-programming

Hope, my question itself, conveys what I am look for.
Will put the words in detail
1. Created the Module.

> var ang = angular.module('myApp', []);

1. I have a controller called controller1, and includes the 'campaign' factory.

> //controllerone.js
>
> ```
> ang.controller('controller1', function(campaign){
>    $scope.campaigns = new campaign();
>    //Here the whole campaign object is displayed with data, refer the Image 1 attached
>    console.log($scope.campaigns); 
> });
> ```

```
ang.factory('campaign', function($http){
  var campaign = function(){
    this.timePeriodList = buildTimePeriodList();
    ...
    ...
    this.campaignList = [];

 };
Campaigns.prototype.fetchCampaigns = function() {
  //Some service call to load the data in this.campaignList
};
});
```

Now trying to call the same campaign factory in the second controller, getting only the object structure, not getting the data.

//controlertwo.js

> ```
> ang.controller('controller2', function(campaign){
>    $scope.campaigns = new campaign();
>    //Here only the campaign object structure is displayed, but no data for campaignList, ref image 2 attached
>    console.log($scope.campaigns); 
> });
> ```

Since, **factory service is a singleton object, I was expecting for same result as I got in controllerone.js,**

Image 1:

[image: Image 1]

Image 2:

[image: Image 2]

Comment: stop using `new` if you want to take benefit of singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Create campaign in a **service**. Eg-campaignService

Updated code---

```
var ang = angular.module('myApp', []);

ang.service('campaignService', function($scope){
    var campaign = function(){
    this.timePeriodList = buildTimePeriodList();
    ...
    ...
    this.campaignList = [];
    }
    return campaign;
});

ang.controller("controller1", ["campaignService",
function($scope, $rootScope, campaignService){
    $scope.campaigns=campaignService.campaign();
}
]);

ang.controller("controller2", ["campaignService",
function($scope, $rootScope, campaignService){
    $scope.campaigns=campaignService.campaign();
    console.log($scope.campaigns);
}
]);
```

Comment: dear friend, are you sure, this way it will work, I do not feel, changing the file name to campaignService.js and new campaignService.campaign(), will help, 
Can you give a jsfiddle demo, if you can

Comment: @SAM : the idea is to use dependency injection(DI) in angularJs. This example is small so you need not create separate js files or else you need to create separate modules and use DI to bind service with controllers. This will help you implement your factory methods separate from controller logic.

Answer (score 0):

In angular factory I would suggest a different approach.Try not to attach anything to the Prototype of a object. Instead you can create an object in the scope of your angular factory, attach what you want to it and return it. For example:

```
     ang.factory('campaign', function ($http) {
var campaign = {};
campaign.method1 = function () {
    //..
}
campaign.campaignList = [];
//...

campaign.fetchCampaigns = function () {
    //Some service call to load the data in this.campaignList
};
```

});

//Than in your controllers if campaign is injected you can use it that way:

```
ang.controller('controller2', function (campaign) {
    campaign.fetchCampaigns();// This will fill the list and it will remain filled when other controllers use this factory...
    console.log(compaign.campaignList);
});
```

Anything you dont want to be exposed out of the factory simply do not attach it to the campaign  object.